# adding price rules to magento products

Tags: magento

I'm trying to put some finishing touches to a magento project, but I have a problem.

When adding products, I need to be able to add 3 vital pieces of information:

1. wholesale cost of product - field available for that
2. % discount on wholesaler list price
3. delivery route (with price) chosen from a select list
4. desired % profit margin

Number 4 can be dealt with an extension I've purchased here:
http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_cost_based_pricing.html

Problem is that the other two fields (2 and 3) I need to be able to factor in.

Has anybody got any extensions that might be able to satisfy these criteria?  Commercial extensions are fine!

Answer (score 0):

Number 2 is doable with [Catalog Price Rules](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_5#catalog_price_rules) (built in) but isn't so easy to specify a % per product, it is really meant for groups of classes of products.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, check out tier pricing abilities of Magento from this screen-cast http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/screencasts/configuring-tier-pricing/view